# Display a list of available views

Tags: view, wiki

I have a Sharepoint Wiki Library and have created a series of views to show different aspects of my Library.

How can I display the list of all available views on one page?

I currently have to go to a single view (by knowing the URL or going through Library Settings) and change view from the dropdown list in the page header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this

**No Code Solution**

1. Create a page
2. Add a content editor webpart
3. Edit the content and add URL to the view using html `a` tags

**Using Server Object Model**

1. Create a visual webpart
2. Get the `SPList` object and use the [SPViewCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.views.aspx) property

**Using Client Object Model**

1. Add a content editor webpart
2. Use below code

   ```
   clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
   var web = clientContext.get_web();
   var listCollection = web.get_lists();
   var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Wiki");
   var viewcollection = list.get_views();
   clientContext.load(viewcollection);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, GetViews), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   ```